# how can i design a CSS style for comment boxes for a Social Networking site. Need some sample code

Tags: html, css

i have created a Social networking site in PHP. but am not good in CSS.  Comments for images, and texts(status) are not good looking, does not have a good separation from each others.

So can anyone give me a CSS style for my site(like facebook having), which follows below logic,

```
  <table class="myTable" width="400">
 <tr  class="image_posts"><td> <img src="img1.jpg">  </td></tr>
        <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-1     </td></tr>
        <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-2     </td></tr>
        <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-3     </td></tr>

    <tr  class="text_posts"><td> STATUS-1    </td></tr>
        <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-1   </td></tr>
        <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-2   </td></tr>
        <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-3   </td></tr>
 </table>
```

Conditions:

> - long "comments or status"(for example, text with 100 letters) should                                                         not exceeds the table width. it should split into 2-3 rows.
> - Comments and text(status) posts should be easily separately identifiable by the user.

Can anyone please give me the code. i have done with my graduation project. i know PHP, but dont know CSS. so please, help me..

Given below my PHP Code to display image posts and text posts with Comments.

```
$query = "select image_id as id, username, time_stamp, title as text_and_title, size, image_url, privacy from image_posts where username='".$_SESSION['valid_user']."'  UNION select text_id as id, username, time_stamp, text, NULL, NULL,privacy from text_posts where username='".$_SESSION['valid_user']."' order by time_stamp desc";
    //  image_id as id,    username,    time_stamp,    title as text_and_title,     size,      image_url,       privacy
    // text_id as id,      username,    time_stamp,    text,                NULL,   NULL,          privacy

    $result = $conn->query($query);

    $num_rows = $result->num_rows;


    if($num_rows > 0) {


        for($count = 0; $count < $num_rows; $count++ ) {

            $row = $result->fetch_object();



            if($row->image_url == NULL) { // then it is a text(status) post



echo "<tr class='fixed_tr'  ><td > Posted On:".$row->time_stamp."<br /><label style=\"width:30px\">".$row->text_and_title."</label></td></tr>" ;



// display comments for texts
$q = "select comment_id,username,comment, time_stamp from comments where text_id='".$row->id."'  order by time_stamp DESC";
$res = $conn->query($q);
$n = $res->num_rows;
if($n > 0) {
for($c = 0; $c < $n; $c++){
    $r = $res->fetch_object();
    echo "<tr class='tr_forComments'  ><td >Commented by:".$r->username."  on  ".$r->time_stamp." <br>".$r->comment."</td></tr>";


}//for

} 

}
```

given below my CSS code for table,

```
table.fixed { 
table-layout:fixed; 
}
table.fixed td { 
overflow: hidden; 
}



.tr_forComments{
     font-family: "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;  
     background-color: #eceff6;  
        border: 1px solid #d4dae8;  
        color: #333333;  
        padding: 10px;  
        font-size: 13px;  
        font-weight: bold;  
}
```

Comment: u can build site in wordpress

Comment: i have already done all code in PHP just needed only some good designing. So why do i try another option to create a new one!

Comment: oh kk..can u please post your css code what u tired up to now?

Comment: you need to hire a web developer (and/or a web designer), OR you learn how to use CSS. this is not a place to get work done for free, i am afraid.

Comment: Also no half-decent web designer still uses tables for layout. Learn CSS and use div-varients instead

Comment: am doing college project. So i cant hire anyone. and i would like to concentrate in server side program only. Thats why am not ready to spend time in CSS. If you can help me, please give me some code, please..

Comment: this is a place where developers who are trying to solve things on their own ask specific questions when they got stuck. it is NOT a place to ask for code just because you don´t want to learn CSS on your own.

Comment: also, you will always need at least html/css for php. you have to learn it anyway.

Comment: actually i know some CSS. but i dont have deeper knowledge to create a supperb design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS is very important to learn for web development. If you want some base CSS styles to start you off, you can use Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com.

Here's a quick overview on how to use it: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/.

You can learn about making an input element (for comments) here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups.

Bootstrap provides a basic design that is a good starter for projects. I suggest learning more CSS to customize Bootstrap. You can learn from these sites:

- http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web
- https://www.codeschool.com/courses/css-cross-country

Answer (score -1):

```
<div="comment_table">   
<table class="myTable" width="400">
<tr  class="image_posts"><td> <img src="img1.jpg">  </td></tr>
    <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-1     </td></tr>
    <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-2     </td></tr>
    <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-3     </td></tr>

<tr  class="text_posts"><td> STATUS-1    </td></tr>
    <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-1   </td></tr>
    <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-2   </td></tr>
    <tr class="image_comments"><td>   COMMENT-3   </td></tr>
 </table>
 </div>
```

I don't think i seen social media like this, but, a current media site will have the tables inside divs like above.
If you have the exact code i can make some css for you, I actually have a website where people can make their own custom profile pages.

You can still make css for the classes, but you can't really move them around the page very well.

Post the whole pages script and i will make you something.

Comment: i have given above the PHP and css code which i used in my site.